# pop a specific view controller

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

I have an hierarchy of 3 view controllers in my navigation bar controller: view1->view2->view3. After the user finished with view3 I want to take him to view1. What is the best approach to do that?

thanks,

Nava

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that view3 and view2 have already been pushed onto your navigation controller, you can use `-[UINavigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:]` or `-[UINavigationController popToViewController:animated:]` to accomplish this.

Comment: if I do it from my view3 how can I be sure I don't leave leaked views?
both functions return an array of view on the stack. The question is whether I can release them?

Comment: If you've used -pushViewController:animated: to push them ONTO the stack, then popTo-whatever will not leak when you remove them from the stack.

Answer (score -1):

Simply make the action of a UIBarButtonItem on your UINavigationController (in this case, most likely your rightBarButtonItem) call

```
[self.myNavController pushViewController:view1 animated: YES];
```