# Switching from one navigation stack to another navigation stack using popViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, popviewcontroller

I have created a module in which i have 5 classes in this i need to perform a task like

vc1->vc2->vc3

now from vc3 i used to push vc4 from the reference of a base class.
base class is a class on which vc1 controller's is added as a subview.

and now i need to pop from vc4 to vc3.

Comment: why you not use Tabbarcontroller with three Tab..?

Comment: This application is already created and i am making some changes so i cannot change the structure of the application.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSInteger index = 0;
for (UIViewController *view in self.navigationController.viewControllers) {
  if([view.nibName isEqualToString:@"YourViewController"])//put any `XIB name` where u want to navigate 
  break;
index = index + 1;
}
 //[[self navigationController] pushViewController:[[self.navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:index] animated:YES];

[[self navigationController] popToViewController:[[self.navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:index] animated:YES];
```

Comment: it will not work please try it by your self i have already done that as you will not get the viewcontroller in the navigation stack coz there will be 2 navigation stacks

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *array = [self.navigationController viewControllers];

[self.navigationController popToViewController:[array objectAtIndex:2] animated:YES];
```

Get the index of the view controller you want to pop to.

Please refer to these links :-

[Can i pop to Specific ViewController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027559/can-i-pop-to-specific-viewcontroller)

[pop a specific view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082539/pop-a-specific-view-controller)